# Flex: How to get the image size of an Image?

Tags: apache-flex, image, flex3

Give an `Image` component, how can I tell the size [width and height] of the bitmap image that the `Image` is containing (not the size of the `Image` component)

Also I want to know this as soon as possible, so I think this needs to be in the Event.COMPLETE event?

Thanks!!

Comment: Found the answer: Image.contentWidth and Image.contentHeight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Image extends SWFLoader, properties `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` are both publicly available. They are available on the ["complete"](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event:complete) event.

Accessing the Image's bitmap data might not be allowed if the Image is loaded from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

The BitmapData class will give you the width and height properties.

This should be available in the

```
protected measure()
```

method, which you can override if you need to do things to it.

Comment: Is there a way to access the BitmapData class of an Image component?